# Where to purchase a simple single-speed?

Tags: single-speed, germany

I would like to purchase a cheap (maybe around 200-300€) and spartanic single-speed racer-like bike. I don't need fancy extras - just wheels, a frame, and brakes (but please no backpadel-brake and with freewheel).

I want to have this kind of bike mainly for the city to be able to make some speed and have fun with it. I don't want the expense and maintenance of gear change on this bike. I don't want the fear of an overprized *steal-inviting* deceiver/poser bike. **Simplicity wins.**

- Where should I search when I am looking for such a bike?

Second hand is an option.

Comment: @Gary.Ray I think the *what* is explained in the other question. I edited my topic.

Comment: Asking where to search for something sounds to me like a service recommendation, which is off topic for this site. Feel free to ask in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/214/the-velodrome) though. You'll get help there for sure.